# Not able to setup my work pc as hosting server using no-ip dynamic DNS

Tags: hosting, dyndns, dynamic-dns

I want to host server on work pc that is behind router, and i dont have access to router.
The IP that my pc gets as subnetted one, i mean i am in LAN and so my routers IP may be 192.168.1.1 and all other pc connected to it have subnetted IP.

Now how am i to point my domain name to my PC IP what settings should i use and how can i do it.. I am already running the client provided by no-ip.org, and i have used my local network dynamic ip.

Comment: I'm sorry but any reasonable answer to this is going to invole either the router you don't have access to, or at least the co-operation of the sysadmins who do have access to that router and the other aspects of your company internet connection. Also, while its strictly speaking none of my business, I'd suggest you speak to those people *anyway* before trying to publish a server to the internet without their knowledge/co-operation. I'm one of those kind of people myself and we all tend towards serious sense of humour failures about unapproved servers connected to the Internet.

Comment: We generally expect people to have the authority and privilege to fix a problem or implement a solution which you don't appear to have. The best we can do is say speak to your sysadmins/manager.

Answer (score 2):

> and i dont have access to router

Then nobody outside your LAN can access your machine. It's not just sub-netted, it's masqueraded (and possibly firewalled too).

Comment: >  so this means no-ip.org is of no use to me. I mean i cannot host server on my pc???? If no then can u suggest any other service so that i can turn my PC to a server (without access to router, and without static ip--- )

Comment: Either get access to the router and enable port forwarding or get a hosted server somewhere - but I'd urge you to learn a lot more about running a website first; running a webserver requires a lot more skills than just serving up content - otherwise you're just providing an asset for other people to abuse.